# Как получить ассоциативный массив jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Нужна помощь с js. Есть таблица, по нажатию кнопки все элементы строки попадают в массив. При выводе консоль лога выглядит все слитно, примерно так ProductNumberProductPriceProductName. Как сделать ассоциативный массив или как можно разбить?

```js
var txt = [];

$(document).on('click', 'input.cart', function () {

        txt.push($(this).closest("td")
                .siblings()
                .text());
    }

 console.log(txt);

});
```

Comment: элементы массива через запятую выводятся, если использовать `console.log`

Comment: и у вас ошибки в примере, поправьте его